# Serial Upvoting Incident

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange, etiquette, up-votes

I had my first incident of serial upvoting (and of its reversal). Yesterday (my time), some good Samaritan, or strong supporter (or tester of the SE system, for that matter), **upvoted in a single minute six of my answers:**

[Deriving and explaining the weighted cost of capital](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/deriving-and-explaining-the-weighted-cost-of-capital/2934#2934)

[What causes the "imperialism of economics" and how did it start?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/what-causes-the-imperialism-of-economics-and-how-did-it-start/1892#1892)

[Comparative dynamics in forward-looking equation](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/comparative-dynamics-in-forward-looking-equation/1887#1887)

[Do large public companies ever "quit while they're ahead"?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/do-large-public-companies-ever-quit-while-theyre-ahead/1886#1886)

[Have there been any true "communist" nations as Marx envisioned?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/have-there-been-any-true-communist-nations-as-marx-envisioned/1882#1882)

[The $\sqrt{N}$ convergence of semiparametric estimators of Newey 94, why does it converges to a normal distribution?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/the-sqrtn-convergence-of-semiparametric-estimators-of-newey-94-why-does-it/1806#1806)

And the SE system functioned as promised: come end of the day, it reversed all of them.

Just in case this was a well-meaning "scheme" by some comrade here to increase reputation levels for the benefit of the site, take heed: *you are being watched*.

Comment: This is actually good to know. Thanks for the heads-up!